# How to translate from one Language to Another In Android

Tags: android, google-app-engine, android-emulator, google-translate, google-translator-toolkit

I have some query.i want to translate from one language to another langugae.i am following this tutorial  http://android-er.blogspot.in/2009/10/androidtranslate-using-google-translate.html but i am not able to translate text.

I am getting error

```
E/ErrorGoogle(1420): java.lang.Exception: Google returned the following error: [403] Please use Translate v2.  See http://code.google.com/apis/language/translate/overview.html
```

can any one tell me why i am getting this error.if any one has faced it before than please help me ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

google v2 API is a paid API, you require an API key to translate.

Read [this](https://developers.google.com/translate/v2/getting_started) for more details. So, I guess you need to find an alternative to google translator.